# Complex Conformal Mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

I'm trying to prove that the mapping

$Z=z^m$

for $m \geq \dfrac 12$, transforms the region $r \geq 0$, $0\leq\theta\leq\dfrac{\pi}{m}$ into the upper half plane $Y\geq 0$ where $Z=X+iY.$

My attempt was to write

$z=re^{i\theta}$  so that

> $$z^m = r^m\bigg[\cos(\theta m) + i\sin(\theta m)\bigg],$$

and the upper-half region would be controlled by $\operatorname{Im}(z)$, so

> $$\operatorname{Im}(z^m) = r^m \sin(\pi)=r^mk$$

so that $k \in [0,1].$

I feel like I am missing why $m$ must be $ \geq \dfrac 12.$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it has to do with your angle range: $0\le\theta\le\pi/m.$ If, say, $m=1/4,$ then you'd be double-covering the complex plane with the inequality $0\le\theta\le4\pi.$

Comment: Yes my thoughts! Thanks for your comment Adrian!